# Getting A field or Entity Generically Based on a String Value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I am trying to write a wrapper function for an application.

This application will continually add entities so it would be better if we could write one generic function rather than have to carve out an exception for each item.

For certain reasons we maintain both a GUID and an int key.

When an int key gets updated, we need to update it both in the parent record the  child records but since it is possible that at any given time there could be multiple child records with the same int key, we need to get a list of Guids of what we want to update.

Here is some psuedo code of what I am trying to do.

```
 List<string> depenedents = new List<string>();
 depenedents.add(table1);
 depenedents.add(table2);
 depenedents.add(table3);

 for(item in depenedents) 
 {
     context.set<type item>();
     entities.getguid();
 }
```

Obviously the issue here is with the for loop.

Is it possible to get a list of entities knowing only the string of the entity type? Luckily all of our entities are wrapped to a base class that has a get guid method, but I need to find a way to actually get the entities.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
     for(item in depenedents) 
 {
     context.GetMethod("Set")
         .MakeGenericType(Type.GetType(item))
         .Invoke(context, new object[0]);

     entities.GetType.GetMethod("GetGuid").Invoke(entities, new object[0]);
 }
```

...should be with roughly what you need. This will invoke the correct type specialisation of the Set generic instance method. Then it will invoke the instance method called "GetGuid" on the entities object.

Or possibly:

```
foreach(var entity in entities)
{
    entity.GetType.GetMethod("GetGuid").Invoke(entities, new object[0]);
}
```

You'll maybe want to do something with the values returned, but hopefully this answer will point you in the right direction!

(and clearly you could optimise this code substantially to cache reflected types and methods, or to use compiled expressions rather than `Invoke()` calls)

Comment: Entities should really be entity form a list of entitites that I call the method getguid on.

Comment: So entities is `List<T>` where `T` is the type whose name is `item`?

Comment: No. I could not invoke these methods so I ended up using a lookup table and some SQL.